# Writing the summary function for a model

Tags: r, package

I am trying to write the summary method for a new model function similar to lm model which i have developed. I would like to know as to how to display the call: in `summary`.

For example:

```
#res <- summary(mod)

# res$call
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = pop_data[[1]])
```

how to write the code to display call text? As above?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you at all?

```
lmcall <- function(formula, data){
  return(as.call(c(quote(lmcall), formula = formula, data = substitute(data))))
}

lmcall(cars$speed ~ cars$dist, data = cars)
#lmcall(formula = cars$speed ~ cars$dist, data = cars)
```